# IOS, Is there a facebook and twitter delegate "didShare"?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, delegates

I have the Facebook and twitter (`TWTweetComposeViewController`) API on mi app. It works just fine, I just want to know if I can override or edit a method or if there's a delegate when the "sharing" is completed and successful. Because I want to call a web-service which increments the number of shares in the database. But its important to be just when it was shared, and not only by tabbing (clicking) the twit or the Facebook icon and then tabbing cancel. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

**UPDATE:** I only need the solution for facebook now.

[image]

Comment: well I just gave up for now, im calling the web service when the "facebookViewController" is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for twitter was actually simple...

```
twitterComposer.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res){

        if (res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone){
            //call the web-service
        }

};
```

But still I don't know how to do this with faceBook...

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the same for Facebook and Twitter. Here's my iOS 7 code:

```
[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
switch (result) {
  case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
    // Your code for when submitted
    NSLog(@"Submitted");
    break;
  case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
    // Your code for when user cancelled
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}];
```